# How to handle a checkbox event in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-redux

I ve to redirect to another page when ever the user checks the checkbox. 
I am new to react-redux. Right now,all I know is to handle submit
button through dispatchaction but I am wondering how to handle 
checkbox action?

```
    export default class myReportForm extends BaseForm {


            return(


                    </form>
                </div>        
        );

        }
    }

    Through handleSubmit in form, I could able to handle submit action. Can any one tell me how to handle checkbox . For example, when I ever click on Afloat , It should redirect me to another page or atleast some action should happen.
```

Comment: @ZackTanner Flagged for not constructive.

Comment: @lux why? Perhaps the user isn't aware that this repo's readme provides a video explanation of how it works. Perhaps OP doesn't know this is a separate library that connects the two.

Comment: @ZackTanner What you just provided is far more useful to a struggling user than simply pasting a link.

Comment: @lux That's why it's a comment, not an answer. Just supplementary information.

Answer (score 3):

*mapStateToProps* and *mapDispatchToActions* are helper functions that will wire up the your component to the redux store. *mapStateToProps* links your component's properties to the state and *mapDispatchToActions* links its events to actions that can be dispatched.

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#container-components

As ever (I'm always recommending this!) have a look at:

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-visibletodolist (the whole course and its follow-up - *Idiomtic Redux* - are great).